# Convert German names written in English letters to German characters?

Tags: english-to-german, diacritic

I am trying to get German characters back in a German. Right now, I am using a simple diacritics table to get it. Is it the right way to do it? Is there a better alternative?

For e.g. I wrote the code below to convert Nervea to Nervä.

```
def diacritics(english_string):
   #replace english characters with german characters.
   english_string = english_string.replace("ae","ä")
   english_string = english_string.replace("oe", "ö")
   english_string = english_string.replace("ue", "ü")
   english_string = english_string.replace("Ae", "Ä")
   english_string = english_string.replace("Oe", "Ö")
   english_string = english_string.replace("Ue", "Ü")
   english_string = english_string.replace("ss", "ß")
   english_string = english_string.replace("SZ", "ß")

   return english_string
```

Comment: Parzival, have you checked the scope of the site? We don’t give programming advice, this is a site for language learners and speakers. Please take the [tour] and browse through our [help] to learn more about how the site works. That said, no, your approach has a fundamental flaw: in German, especially in names, we have both ‘ae’ and ‘ä’, ‘oe’ and ‘ö’, etc.

Comment: Yes. I only showed the code to help people understand what I am trying to get. That's why I wrote the code in python because I thought people would understand it better than my English. My english is not that good. I used a translator but didn't have any success with it because translators don't translate names. That's why I posted here.

Comment: So, I am guessing its not possible to go from English charcters to German characters.

Comment: @Stephie I don't think it's completely out of scope. But yes, it's on the edge. As you said, one can see it as algorithm-proofreading, but also as "Is it always possible to convert ae, oe, etc. into Umlauts". Parzival probably should edit it :) .

Comment: @mtwde which is why I didn’t VTC (others did already) and asked for clarification instead. In any case, this question needs an [edit].

Comment: This is only possible with a lookup table for every known word as there are words and names that do contain "ue" and the like.

Comment: @mtwde Thank you. That is what I was trying to ask but my english is not good and the page where you input question showed python, so I wrote simplest code I could to help people understand. Guess I should have written algortihm.

Comment: @Stephie: Ein VTC ist meist die richtige Form, nach Klärung zu fragen. Nach erfolgreicher Klärung kann dann wieder geöffnet werden. Außer Du gehst davon aus, das wahrscheinlich nur Du die Frage nicht richtig verstehst. Bevor Fragen, die offtopic oder unklar sind, beantwortet werden, sollten sie temporär geschlossen werden, sonst ermuntert man die Frager OT-Fragen zu stellen, die Anderen mit Antworten zu OT-Fragen Reputation einzusammeln und muss später gute Antworten, die aber nicht mehr zur korrigierten Frage passen, abwerten bzw. löschen.

Comment: @userunknown ist mir sehr wohl bewusst. In diesem Fall habe *ich* die Frage primär in dem Sinne verstanden, wie sie auch gemeint war (womit sie für mich nicht zu schließen war), ging aber davon aus, dass manche Leser sie als Programmierungsproblem verstehen können und habe deshalb den Frager angesprochen, was auch innerhalb kürzester Zeit funktioniert hat. Nur hatte ich keine Zeit mehr, die Frage zu editieren, sonst wären die Kommentare bereits gelöscht bzw als “no longer needed” geflaggt. Trotzdem danke für den Hinweis.

Comment: @Stephie: For me, the question is still unclear. How can he ask us, how to get back to German characters, when we don't know what he is talking about? Did a program translate them, and if so, which one? If his mapping is the opposite mapping, of what the program did, yes, he could do it like this, with the small restriction, that there are no genuine combinations of ae, eo, ue and so on, which is easily to look up in an dictionary. For his first example I immediately find "aerob". So no, it's not the right way to do it, like idmean mentioned before. …

Comment: Idmeans second suggestion is a better way to do it but already in programming topics. To find out, that this is still not sufficient, you need to lookup all Words containing Ae and the like and check, that no matching Ä-word with different meaning exists (Maße, Masse). Then you could go for word tables and distances and try at least a good estimation from the context, whether it is more likely a Maße or Masse. But what is Nervä? Oh, Google finde Songtexte in Mundart: "Fahr emal - ich verlüür grad mini Nervä". Dann sind die Wörterbücher und Distanztabellen gestorben.

Answer (score 16):

Names may contain *ae, oe, ue*:

> Baedeker [ɛː]
>   Goethe [øː]
>   Fuest* [uː]

Note that adjacent vowels may also belong to different syllables:

> Michael [ˈmɪça.(ʔ)eːl]
>   Oboe [oˈboː.ə]
>   eventuell [evɛntʊˈɛl]

Therefore, no automatic translation from *ae, oe, ue* to *ä, ö, ü* is possible.

The graphemes *ss, ß* are used to distinguish the length of the preceding vowel. Therefore, one cannot be substituted for the other.

> Maße [maːsə]
>   Masse [masə]

Also, there are many complex words where two adjacent *s* belong to different morphemes:

> aus+sehen, weis+sagen, los+stürmen …

*<sub>Note that *Fuest* belongs to a group of names where *e* does not indicate umlaut but length of the preceding vowel.</sub>

Comment: This could go into the "Michael" block: "Ausschalter" cannot be turned into "Außchalter"

Comment: "Quelle"! would be non-proper noun where translation wouldn't work, and creates another category.

Comment: “Qübec” will annoy all Canadians.

Comment: Was ist mit Nervä?

Comment: "The graphemes ss, ß are used to distinguish the length of the preceding vowel. Therefore, one cannot be substituted for the other." - if *ß* is not available, replacing *ß* with *ss* is indeed the typical way to go. But I agree some information is lost in the process and the inverse substitution cannot be done purely by looking at the letters.

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe eine blaue Jacke und einen grauen Mantel. Ich sah zwei Pfauen im Park.

Lots of words contain these letter combinations and are bout umlauts.

Comment: Was ist mit Nervä?